# Is 'good' a double-entendre in some parts of the US?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, idiom-meaning

In the movie [The Incredibles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredibles), the characters [have the following dialogue](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Incredibles,-The.html):

> LUCIUS (FROZONE): Honey?
>
> HONEY: What?
>
> LUCIUS (FROZONE): Where's my supersuit?
>
> HONEY: What?
>
> LUCIUS (FROZONE): Where is my supersuit?
>
> HONEY: I, uh...put it away.
>
> LUCIUS (FROZONE): Where?
>
> HONEY: Why do you need to know?
>
> LUCIUS (FROZONE): I need it!
>
> HONEY: Uh-uh! Don't you think about running off doing no derrin'-do! We've been planning this dinner for two months!
>
> LUCIUS (FROZONE): The public is in danger!
>
> HONEY: My evening's in danger!
>
> LUCIUS (FROZONE): You tell me where my suit is, woman! We are talking about the greater good!
>
> HONEY: "Greater good"? I am your wife! I'm the greatest **good** you are ever gonna get!

The wife appears to be implying that ***good*** has a double-meaning.

In the West Wing Episode [20 Hours in America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20_Hours_in_America) - we [see the following interchange](http://www.westwingtranscripts.com/search.php?flag=getTranscript&id=68):

> TOBY: Afternoon.
>
> FIONA: Yes.
>
> TOBY: We'd like some food to go.
>
> FIONA: What would you like?
>
> TOBY: What's **good**?
>
> FIONA: Everything.
>
> TOBY: What's your specialty?
>
> FIONA: Taking someone's order and giving it to them.
>
> TOBY: Okay.
>
> FIONA: I saw you drive up. You people going to cause trouble.
>
> TOBY: I swear not on purpose.
>
> FIONA: Everytime he comes around here, there's trouble. I don't want leaflets around my place. You handing out leaflets?
>
> TOBY: No, uh, we just want food.
>
> FIONA: Yeah, well, what to do need?
>
> TOBY: You wouldn't say there was some sort of local delicacy...
>
> FIONA: I'm getting my husband.

Here we see the wife start to get offended when Toby asks here "What's ***good***?"

My question is: **Is 'good' a double-entendre in some parts of the US?**

Comment: What makes you think it is?

Comment: No, no inherent second 'racy' meaning. In the Incredibles exchange, Honey is just saying that whatever Frozone thinks is good, marrying her is always going to be a better thing. For Toby and Fiona... it's very common for a customer to ask what they think would be good on the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it can be, [good](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=good&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=) is a hard-working word with many meanings and senses as the link to wordnet shows.